# I'm getting an error when calling exec in a Meteor app - Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined

Tags: node.js, meteor

This is the full error:

Internal exception while processing message `{ msg: 'method', method: 'myServerMethod', params: [], id: '4' }` Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined

```js
Meteor.methods
  myServerMethod: ->
    cmd = 'pwd'
    exec cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) ->
```

I could not, for the life of me, know why I'm getting that error. I also tried this on two different machines.

What things do I need to check?

Answer (score 6):

This error usually indicates that your method is trying to return something that is not [EJSON-able](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson), so if it's not on that list then that's why you're getting an error.  In particular, you cannot return a cursor, you need to `fetch` the results and return them.

Comment: Another thing to note is that CoffeeScript by default returns the value of the last expression in a function, so you might be returning something you didn't mean to. You can prevent this by adding a blank `return` to the end of the function.

Comment: I think you guys are correct - I created a "test.sh" and just echo a valid json data and i got it back. However, where can I put this relative to my current meteor directory because no matter where i put it inside the .meteor directory Meteor always says "[Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: test.sh: command not found". The only way i was able to make this work is to put my shell script in one of my $PATH folder.

Comment: Same problem for me. I just had to return something and that fixed the error!